# Java serialization socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, server, client

The goal of my work is the implementation of a collaborative and distributed computing platform. Indeed, the idea is to allow a client to perform an operation of one of these classes via a server. I use for this the serialization. Everything goes well for the transfer of the class and when I perform the operation, but when I want to return the result to the client, nothing happens and I do not understand why. Would anyone have an explanation to give me? :)

thanks,

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] zero) {

        Socket socket;

        try {

            // on ouvre la connexion
            System.out.println("Création du socket de la part du client");
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2009);

            System.out.println("Début de la sérialization du client ");

            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

            try {
                // création du fichier avec la classe FileOutputStream
                final FileOutputStream fichier = new FileOutputStream("calcul.ser");

                // le résultat de la serialization est envoyé dans le fichier
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fichier);

                // création d'un objet à sérializer
                Calcul calc = new Calcul("1", "6");

                // sérialization de l'objet et envoi
                oos.writeObject(calc);

                // on vide le tampon
                oos.flush();


            } catch (final java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (oos != null) {
                        oos.flush();
                        oos.close();
                    }
                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            BufferedReader inFromUser =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

            BufferedReader inFromServer =
                    new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 

            String resultat = inFromServer.readLine(); 

            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + resultat); 

            socket.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}


public class Serveur {

    public static void main(String[] zero) {

        ServerSocket socketserver;
        Socket socketduserveur;
        String resultat = null;

        try {
            // connexion au client
            socketserver = new ServerSocket(2009);

                socketduserveur = socketserver.accept();

                //on lance la deserialization 
                ObjectInputStream ois = null;

                try {

                    // création du fichier avec FileInputStream
                    final FileInputStream fichier = new FileInputStream("calcul.ser");

                    // le résultat de la déserialization est envoyé dans le fichier 
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(fichier);

                    // on stock dans calcul l'objet deserializé
                    final Calcul calcul = (Calcul) ois.readObject();

                    //on additionne les deux nombre dans la classe calcul
                     resultat = String.valueOf(calcul.Addition());

                    System.out.println("le resultat de l'addition au niveau du serveur est :" + calcul.getResultat());


                } catch (final java.io.IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (ois != null) {
                            ois.close();
                        }
                    } catch (final IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                DataOutputStream outToClient =
                        new DataOutputStream(socketduserveur.getOutputStream());

                outToClient.writeBytes(resultat); 


            socketserver.close();
            socketduserveur.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

import java.io.Serializable;

//création de notre classe sérializable
public class Calcul implements Serializable {

    // les objets int sont sérializables pas de soucis 
    private String nombre1,nombre2;
    private int resultat;

    //création du constructeur
    public Calcul (String nombre1, String nombre2) {
        this.nombre1=nombre1;
        this.nombre2=nombre2;
    }

    //création de la méthode addition qui va être exécutée sur le serveur
    public int Addition() {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(nombre1);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(nombre2);
        resultat = x+y;
        return resultat;
    }

    public int getResultat() {
        return resultat;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you never called outToClient.flush().

I would also pont that you agressively close the socket (causing a TCP RST) because you didn't close the socket streams (TCP FIN). That leaves no chance for the OS to flush out packets even if you called flush. The proper way is to flush, close streams, then close socket. Also, only one should initiate the close, the other should detect EOF and then proceed with its close.Otherwise, you have 2 peers eager to hangup, which can lead to missing data.

Comment: Yeah true thank you but the problem is not yet solved

Comment: `outToClient` is a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around the socket's output stream, and neither of these is buffered, so no `flush()` is required. I don't know what exactly you mean by 'aggressive close' but there is nothing in the way this socket is closed that would inherently cause an RST rather than a FIN. Closing the streams or the socket closes the other streams and the socket, in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the output on your serveur console ? Because I see you do a sysout on your server. And resultat is casted as String I guess you need to cast it on Bytes before doing `outToClient.writeBytes(resultat);` Because it is a writeBytes. I can remember if there is something to write strings directly but try casting your variable resultat on bytes and add a flush

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The method writeBytes(resultat) allow to pass String directly, normally it's working. I tried to convert the String in byte[] but it's not working :     
'DataOutputStream outToClient =
      new DataOutputStream(socketduserveur.getOutputStream());
    
     //byte [] resultatByte = resultat.getBytes();
     
    //outToClient.write(resultatByte);
    outToClient.writeBytes(resultat); 
    
    outToClient.flush();'
ps : i've no output of the string on my server console

Comment: Glad i'm helpfull. For the no output on server your client doesn't send anything so it's normal. I can't figure out why I asked for that x)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

I just put a thread.sleep(2000) at the end of my serveur and client Class. I think that i couldn't see the system.out.println of my client because it was overiden by Serveur !!

Thanks a lot, happy coding :)